# How are badges ordered on the profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page, badges

I wonder how badges ordered on the profile page:

[image]

Is it random? I couldn't see any non-random pattern.

Comment: Not really a dupe. Is the answer "ordered by descending rarity"?

Comment: Yes. I found another (different) question where the answer explains how these are determined.